# Android get closest character or word end

Tags: android

I'm using `indexof()` to find the length of a specific character, then color it with different color. I can start the coloring exactly with the character using the `indexof()` which is great, but I can't end it to the word.

```
if(title.contains("x")){

    SpannableString WordtoSpan = new SpannableString(title);        
    WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), title.indexOf("x"), title.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    holder.txtTitle.setText(WordtoSpan);
} else {
    holder.txtTitle.setText(title);
}
```

Now if it contains the character `x` it will color it with red from the first `x` it finds. But it won't end until the last of the string which I dont like.

I want it to end with the end of the word that started with an `x`.

**ex.** Now: (Bold is the color red atm)

> I love **x-man and chocolate.**

What I want is:

> I love **x-man** and chocolate.

how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must find where the word ends, not simply passing length();

Consider a more robust algorithm to find word separator (ie include tabs), in the example I simply find the first whitespace

```
    String s = "I love x-man and chocolate.";

    int idx = s.indexOf("x");

    if (idx >= 0) {
        int wordEnd = s.indexOf(" ", idx);
        if (wordEnd < 0) {
            wordEnd = s.length();
        }
        WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),
                    idx,
                    wordEnd,
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
```